# Shared Preferences default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I noticed when using `SharedPreferences`, specifically `EditTextPreference`, that in the xml file there is an `android:defaultValue` option and when I try to use `SharedPreferences` in my class I have to use:

```
int variable = (Integer.parseInt(sp.getString(key, defaultValue)));
```

Is that default value the same as the set `android:defaultValue`? Should I set them as the same value? What happens if they are different?

Comment: Nothing happens if they're different. You can set defaultValue manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set them to be the same. Why the Android team at Google did not create an overloaded method that does not take a default value like `getString(String key)` is beyond me. If the values are different, you will get the value you set on `android:defaultValue` on your XML.

Comment: I thought the same thing, there should be an overloaded method. Thank you!